# Can't create django(1.11) superuser on mac

Tags: python, django, macos

I m trying to create superuser in Django (1.11) on Python (3.6.4) on Mac (10.13.3).

After entering username, I'm pressing `enter`. `enter` won't take me to next input.

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'neon'): admin^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^C^CKeyboardInterrupt

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/neon/workspace/jp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.11-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/neon/workspace/jp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.11-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/neon/workspace/jp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.11-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/neon/workspace/jp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.11-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/neon/workspace/jp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.11-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/neon/workspace/jp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.11-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 116, in handle
    username = self.get_input_data(self.username_field, input_msg, default_username)
  File "/Users/neon/workspace/jp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-1.11-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 192, in get_input_data
    raw_value = input(message)
SystemError: <built-in function input> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your terminal or your input. Try to open a new terminal or it might also be helpful to reboot the machine and check if the keyboards is OK.

Comment: For username your input was 
 `admin^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^M^C` and there was a keyboard interrupt at the end.

Comment: Please if you see ^M because of some reason I always use `Ctrl + J` instead of `Enter`

Comment: Thanks, both `ctrl+j ` & trying cmds in new terminal worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, both <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and running command in new terminal worked.